# Adapting C# code for SQL linked server to work directly with Sybase

Tags: c#, sap-ase

I have an application written in C# that utilizes a linked server in MS SQL Server.  The linked server hosts a Sybase database.  I have code that successfully performs a lookup in a table on the linked server, but I have recently been instructed to access the linked server directly, due to performance issues.

I would like to share the code that worked correctly with use of a linked server in the hope that my intention can be easily understood. Then I would like some help on where I am failing to correctly write this to work with Sybase.  I readily admit part of the problem is that I'm new to this.  This is my first C# application.

```
    private SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        int ScanCheck(string Agin, string UCC)
        {
        //This will open the SQL database connection for checking the
        //variables 'Agin' and 'UCC' as lookup values for a single record
        //containing both (defined and populated in an earlier part of the code).  

        //Stored procedure "ScanCheck" is executed.  If a record is found, variable @Scans will be 
        //assigned a value of 1.

        //establish connection to db
        con.ConnectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.setDBPath;
        con.Open();


        //set up the sql command to increment hit count.
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "ScanCheck";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Agin", Agin);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UCC", UCC);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Scans", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        int Scans = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@Scans"].Value);
        cmd.Dispose();
        return Scans;
        }
```

//The code above works as intended.

//Here is my attempt to access Sybase directly.  I get an error at the line cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

```
    private AseConnection con = new AseConnection();
    int ScanCheck(string Agin, string UCC)
        {
        con.ConnectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.TMS;
        con.Open();


        AseCommand cmd = new AseCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "Select @Scans = count(1) from Database.dbo.Table where whsl_agin_nbr = @Agin and mstr_ucc_cd = @UCC";

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Agin", Agin);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UCC", UCC);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Scans", AseDbType.Integer).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;


        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        int Scans = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@Scans"].Value);
        cmd.Dispose();
        return Scans;

    }
```

The error I receive is:

> Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseException  {"Unsupported parameter type"}

Comment: Don't use `AddWithValue`. Specify the `AseDbType` for every parameter and include the size as required by the type. I would advise you to call the `Add` overload that takes an `AseParameter` argument because you can use an object initializer with it. This will also allow you to store the parameter object for the output parameter so you don't have to us the indexer to retrieve it. Using `.Value` or `.Direction` on the result of `Add` is clumsy.

Comment: In addition to the above as general advice, it's possible that `AseParameter` is incorrectly inferring the type of the first two parameters.